# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 11

Tags: android, saxparser

I am working on the sax XML parsing.

Logcat error like...

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 11
```

I got the error at

```
map.put("pubdate", sitesList.getPubdate().get(i));

for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("value of i==============>"+i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println("\nvalue of title==============>"+ sitesList.getName().get(i));

        map.put("title", sitesList.getName().get(i));
        map.put("pubdate", sitesList.getPubdate().get(i));
        map.put("desc", sitesList.getDesc().get(i));

         items.add(map);

    }
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: There isn't one at 11. Other than that, we're guessing, because we cannot see the xml.

Comment: Do you know for sure that `getPubDate` has the same size as `getName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all,
Finally I got the solution For my problem, Here the sitesList.getName() is bigger than sitesList.getPubdate() , so Now I use

for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getPubdate().size(); i++)  in place of
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++)

```
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getPubdate().size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("value of i==============>"+i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        map.put("title", sitesList.getName().get(i));
        map.put("pubdate", sitesList.getPubdate().get(i));
        map.put("desc", sitesList.getDesc().get(i));

         items.add(map);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the sitesList.getName() has the same size of sitesList.getPubdate()?

Because the only reason for that exception is that sitesList.getName() is bigger than sitesList.getPubdate() :)

Comment: Thanks,Yes You are right,sitesList.getName() is bigger than sitesList.getPubdate(). How can i solve for that.

Comment: Well now you have to understand why they have different size and correct that problem :) To solve that problem you can check which list has the min size and use that size as guard for your for loop but with this solution you will miss some data if you have a larger list (as in your case). As I said, before, try to understand why you have different sizes

Comment: I am working for the SAX xml parsing for the "http://news.google.com/?output=rss"  getname() is value of the title and getpubdate() is value of the date.

Answer (score 1):

i think here size of sitesList,

Use `sitesList.size()` **instead of** `sitesList.getName().size()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("value of i==============>"+i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println("\nvalue of title==============>"+ sitesList.get(i).getName());

        map.put("title", sitesList.get(i).getName());
        map.put("pubdate", sitesList.get(i).getPubdate());
        map.put("desc", sitesList.get(i).getDesc());

        items.add(map);

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Oh, now I do. Explain in text, not in a comment.

Comment: @Dave Newton see OP use wron conditioin in for loop

Comment: @SamirMangroliya I don't think his code would even compile if that was the issue.

Comment: @assylias Totally depends; if it's all generic XML objects then it likely would compile but break at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Souldnt your loop look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("value of i==============>"+i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println("\nvalue of title======>"+ sitesList.get(i).getName());

        map.put("title", sitesList.get(i).getName());
        map.put("pubdate", sitesList.get(i).getPubdate());
        map.put("desc",sitesList.get(i).getDesc());

         items.add(map);

    }
```